# Toggle camera in OpenTok Swift SDK

Tags: ios, swift, videocall

I am using OpenTok SDK for Video calling in my application. I need to implement camera Toggle functionality on a button click. But its not working.

I am using

`@IBAction func cameraButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
     publisher?.cameraPosition = AVCaptureDevice.Position.back
}`
 on button click

And publisher is created when session is connected

```
  func sessionDidConnect(_ session: OTSession) {
    print("The client connected to the OpenTok session.")
    let settings = OTPublisherSettings()
    settings.name = UIDevice.current.name 
    guard let publisher = OTPublisher(delegate: self, settings: settings) else {
        return
    }

    var error: OTError?
    session.publish(publisher, error: &error)
    guard error == nil else {
        print(error!)
        return
    }

    guard let publisherView = publisher.view else {
        return
    }
    let screenBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
    publisherView.frame = CGRect(x: screenBounds.width - 150 - 20, y: screenBounds.height - 150 - 20, width: 150, height: 150)
    view.addSubview(publisherView)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are not setting the publisher. It's a simple mistake, could happen to anyone.

```
guard let publisher = OTPublisher(delegate: self, settings: settings) else {
    return
}

self.publisher = publisher
```

Add this line to your code where you are initializing the publisher.